# Convert YYYYQ using as.yearqtr

Tags: r, date, date-format, zoo

I have a char field with the format YYYYQ (e.g., 20124, 20131, etc) and I want to convert it to a field format by using as.yearqtr from the zoo package.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** Be sure to convert to character first:

```
library(zoo)

x <- c(20124, 20131)

as.yearqtr(format(x), "%Y%q")
## [1] "2012 Q4" "2013 Q1"
```

**2)** This would also work.  It converts the number to year + fraction of a year:

```
as.yearqtr(x %/% 10 + ((x %% 10) - 1)/4)
## [1] "2012 Q4" "2013 Q1"
```

**3)** as would this which converts the number to yyyy-0q first:

```
as.yearqtr(sub("(.)$", "-0\\1", x))
## [1] "2012 Q4" "2013 Q1"
```